# Flex Mobile - Custom Spark List ItemRenderer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, air, itemrenderer

I am looking for some guidance to create a custom Spark List ItemRenderer for an Flex Mobile application I am developing.

Overview:  Section List where each item has a checkbox control, Label, button control 1 - opens an accordion list below the item, button control 2 - opens Camera UI.

What I am struggling with is creating an itemrenderer that allows the accoridion list to be visible and be populated.

Update: Here's my existing code

```
<fx:Metadata>

    [Event(name="checkBoxIconItemRendererChanged", type="flash.events.Event")]
    [Event(name="cameraIconItemRendererChanged", type="flash.events.Event")]

</fx:Metadata>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import spark.components.Label;
        import spark.components.CheckBox;
        import spark.components.HGroup;
        import spark.components.Image;
        import spark.layouts.HorizontalAlign;

        import flashx.textLayout.formats.VerticalAlign;
        //camera stuff
        public var cameraIcon:Image;
        public var friendsIcon:Image;

        //checkbox stuff start
        public var checkBox:CheckBox;
        private var checkBoxChanged:Boolean;
        private var _checkBoxField:String;
        private var _checkBoxFunction:Function;

        //list item group
        public var listGroup:HGroup;

        private var dataSource:IDataInput;

        public function get checkBoxFunction():Function{    
            return _checkBoxFunction;
        }

        public function get checkBoxField():String{ 
            return _checkBoxField;
        }

        public function set checkBoxFunction(value:Function):void{
            if(_checkBoxFunction==value){
                return;
            }

            _checkBoxFunction=value;
            checkBoxChanged=true;
            invalidateProperties();
        }

        public function set checkBoxField(value:String):void{
            if(_checkBoxField==value){
                return;
            }
            checkBoxChanged=true;
            _checkBoxField=value;
            invalidateProperties();
        }



        /*override public function set data(value:Object):void  
        {
            checkBoxChanged=true;
            super.data = value; //->invalidateProperties();
        }*/

        override protected function createChildren():void
        {
            super.createChildren();

            listGroup = new HGroup();
            var testLabel:Label = new Label();
            testLabel.text = "Test Item";
            listGroup.addElement(testLabel);
            //listGroup.addChild(testLabel);
            listGroup.visible = false;
            listGroup.includeInLayout = false;
            addChild(listGroup);

            checkBox = new CheckBox();  
            //checkBox.skin = skins.ChallengeCheckBox; //throws error in the Skin
            checkBox.width=64;//32
            checkBox.height=64;//32
            checkBox.scaleY=1;//.5
            checkBox.scaleX=1;//.5
            addChild(checkBox);
            //listGroup.addChild(checkBox);

            checkBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(event:MouseEvent):void{    
                dispatchEvent(new Event("checkBoxIconItemRendererChanged"));
            });

            friendsIcon = new Image();
            friendsIcon.source = "assets/controls/eye_lightgray.png";
            friendsIcon.verticalAlign = VerticalAlign.MIDDLE;
            //cameraIcon.horizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.RIGHT;
            friendsIcon.width = 85;
            friendsIcon.height = 85;
            //cameraIcon.x = 275;
            friendsIcon.x = Capabilities.screenResolutionX - 205;
            friendsIcon.buttonMode = true;
            friendsIcon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,showFriends);
            addChild(friendsIcon);
            //listGroup.addChild(friendsIcon);

            cameraIcon = new Image();
            cameraIcon.source = "assets/controls/uncheckedbox.png";
            friendsIcon.verticalAlign = VerticalAlign.MIDDLE;
            //cameraIcon.horizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.RIGHT;
            cameraIcon.width = 85;
            cameraIcon.height = 85;
            //cameraIcon.x = 275;
            cameraIcon.x = Capabilities.screenResolutionX - 105;
            cameraIcon.buttonMode = true;
            cameraIcon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,launchCameraUI);
            addChild(cameraIcon);
        }

        override protected function measure():void  
        {
            super.measure();    
            measuredWidth+=getStyle("horizontalGap")+checkBox.width*checkBox.scaleY;
            measuredHeight=Math.max(measuredHeight, checkBox.height*checkBox.scaleY);   
        }

        override protected function layoutContents(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void    
        {
            var paddingLeft:Number   = getStyle("paddingLeft");
            var paddingRight:Number  = getStyle("paddingRight");
            var paddingTop:Number    = getStyle("paddingTop");
            var paddingBottom:Number = getStyle("paddingBottom");
            var horizontalGap:Number = getStyle("horizontalGap");
            var verticalAlign:String = getStyle("verticalAlign");

            setStyle("paddingLeft",paddingLeft+checkBox.width*checkBox.scaleX+horizontalGap);                    
            super.layoutContents(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);                
            setStyle("paddingLeft",paddingLeft);

            var vAlign:Number;

            if (verticalAlign == "top")
                vAlign = 0;
            else if (verticalAlign == "bottom")
                vAlign = 1;
            else // if (verticalAlign == "middle")  
                vAlign = 0.5;

            var viewHeight:Number = unscaledHeight - paddingTop  - paddingBottom;
            var checkBoxDisplayY:Number = Math.round(vAlign * (viewHeight - checkBox.height*checkBox.scaleY)) + paddingTop;
            checkBox.x=paddingLeft;
            checkBox.y=checkBoxDisplayY;           
        }

        override protected function commitProperties():void 
        {
            super.commitProperties();
            if(checkBoxChanged){
                checkBoxChanged=false;                   

                if (checkBoxFunction != null)
                {
                    checkBox.selected=checkBoxFunction(data);   
                }
                else if (checkBoxField) 
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        if (checkBoxField in data && data[checkBoxField] != null)
                            checkBox.selected=data[checkBoxField];  
                    }
                    catch(e:Error)  
                    {
                        trace(e.message);   
                    }   
                }   
            }
        }
        //end

        private var _backgroundSection:Number = 0xDDDDDD; //this is a grey

        public function set backgroundSection(value:Number):void {
            _backgroundSection = value;
        }

        private var _normalLabelField:String = "kick";

        public function get normalLabelField():String {
            return _normalLabelField;
        }

        public function set normalLabelField(value:String):void {
            _normalLabelField = value;
        }

        private var _sectionField:String = "points";

        public function get sectionField():String {
            return _sectionField;
        }

        public function set sectionField(value:String):void {
            if (value == _sectionField)
                return;

            _sectionField = value;
            invalidateProperties();
        }

        /**
         * Change the style based on the data: section item or regular item
         */
        override public function set data(value:Object):void {
            //checkbox
            checkBoxChanged=true;

            if (value[_sectionField]) {
                labelField = _sectionField;
                labelDisplay.setStyle("textAlign", "center");
                labelDisplay.setStyle("fontWeight", "bold");
            } else {
                labelField = _normalLabelField;
                labelDisplay.setStyle("textAlign", "left");
                labelDisplay.setStyle("fontWeight", "normal");
                //labelDisplay.width = 300;
                //labelDisplay.wordWrap = true;
                //labelDisplay.multiline = true;
            } 
            super.data = value;    
        }

        override protected function drawBackground(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
            super.drawBackground(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
            //change the background if we render for a section title item
            if (data[_sectionField]) {
                graphics.beginFill(_backgroundSection, 1);
                graphics.lineStyle();
                graphics.drawRect(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
                graphics.endFill();
                //adding .parent to each, adding listGroup as parent reference
                /*if (checkBox.parent.parent != null)
                    listGroup.removeChild(checkBox);
                if (friendsIcon.parent.parent != null)
                    listGroup.removeChild(friendsIcon);*/

                if (checkBox.parent != null)
                    removeChild(checkBox);
                if (friendsIcon.parent != null)
                    removeChild(friendsIcon);
                if (cameraIcon.parent != null)
                    removeChild(cameraIcon);
            }
        }

        protected function launchCameraUI(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var cUI:CameraRoll = new CameraRoll();
            if( CameraRoll.supportsBrowseForImage )
            {
                cUI.addEventListener( MediaEvent.SELECT, imageSelected );
                cUI.addEventListener( Event.CANCEL, browseCanceled );
                cUI.addEventListener( ErrorEvent.ERROR, mediaError );
                cUI.browseForImage();
            }
            else
            {
                trace( "Image browsing is not supported on this device.");
            } 
        }

        protected function imageSelected(event:MediaEvent):void
        {
            trace( "Media selected..." );      
            var imagePromise:MediaPromise = event.data;
            dataSource = imagePromise.open();

            if( imagePromise.isAsync )
            {
                trace( "Asynchronous media promise." );
                var eventSource:IEventDispatcher = dataSource as IEventDispatcher;            
                eventSource.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, onMediaLoaded );         
            }
            else
            {
                trace( "Synchronous media promise." );
                readMediaData();
            }
        }

        protected function browseCanceled(event:Event):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        protected function mediaError(event:ErrorEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        private function onMediaLoaded( event:Event ):void
        {
            trace("Media load complete");
            readMediaData();
        }

        private function readMediaData():void
        {
            //do something with the data
        }

        protected function showFriends(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (listGroup.visible == true)
            {
                listGroup.visible = false;
                listGroup.includeInLayout = false;
                trace("Hide Friends Drop Down");
            }
            else
            {
                listGroup.visible = true;
                listGroup.includeInLayout = true;
                trace("Show Friends Drop Down");
            }
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Im using the following as the base code: http://corlan.org/2011/07/04/creating-flex-mobile-section-lists/

UPDATE: Ultimately I would like to create the following [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5N5s.png) where the checkbox is independent of the list item & when you touch the eye icon it opens an accordian style list:

Comment: Post your code in the question itself, not in a link.

Comment: Sorry about that - see update...

Comment: How are you setting checkboxFunction, checkboxField, bacgroundSection, etc?  I don't see those being called in your code snippet.   Those setter functions look suspicious to me; if you're trying to call functions on an itemRenderer instance from code outside the class itself, you're using the itemRenderer wrong.  Everything in an itemRenderer should come from the `data` value.

Comment: Brian - checkboxFunciton and checkboxField are set in commitProperties(), backgroundSection is in drawBackground.  They are mistyped for 'public' and are not called outside this itemrenderer.  Thanks for all your input so far.

Comment: I see that checkBoxFunction gets *called* in commitProperties(), but I don't see where you *set* it in the first place.  Ditto with checkBoxField.

Comment: Its not set anywhere, in this class or the List control.  Maybe I've over complicated this.